# How to maintain the state of fragment object in configuration changes in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to maintain the state of fragment object in configuration changes in android.I am adding fragment dynamically
can anybody provide example

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by state of a fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add a configChanges property to your FragmentActivity declared in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourFragmentActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation" />
```